# Metro Icon - how to obey the user theme?

Tags: visual-studio, microsoft-metro

I've tried setting my app icon to have a transparent background (png), but when this appears on the start screen the transparency is now white.

How can I make it so that the icon background obeys the users preference for tile colours?

Comment: Erm, wait, there is no such thing as "user preference for tile colors".  It is your tile, you color it.

Comment: Maybe I'm expressing it incorrectly, but if you go to :  
  
settings -> change pc settings -> personalise -> start screen.  
  
There is a colour theme bar at the bottom and certain tiles obey this theme colour setting (VS2012 for example installs its own tile which then takes on an appropriate back ground based on the colour scheme).  
  
It was my assumption that to be a 'good metro citizen' I should obey this setting somehow.

Comment: No.  Double-click your appxmanifest, Application UI tab, first Background color setting.  You cannot leave it blank or use a color with an alpha of 0.